# Merging git tags from multiple reference locations

Tags: git, git-tag

We're at a relatively big shop, and we create many builds. I do tag the revisions used for the builds with annotated tags, not only to simplify accessing build history, but also to stash build metadata into the annotation.

Now some folks complain about the many many build tags in existence, so I had the bright idea to stash them into a separate ref on the central master git repo from which everyone clones.

So I would put build tags into `refs/builds/tags` and also stash some moving references (e.g. master-latest-build) into `refs/builds/heads`.

So far so good. This does have the right properties for most developers, who will no longer see the tags and special branches when they use the default refspec.

The problem I'm having is that git doesn't seem to like it if I try to merge together both the "public" tags and the build tags.

I try to do this in my git config:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://gerrit.myshop.com:29418/codebase.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/builds/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/builds/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
    fetch = +refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/commits
```

but when I try to run `git remote show origin`, it lists all my build tags as "stale", and running a `git fetch --prune` will remove them all, only to recreate them. I assume this is because refs/tags is after refs/build/tags, and its state "wins".

Is there a better way to do what I want to do, namely selectively hide some branches and tags without forcing every developer to change the default git configs?

**Update**

The config above actually works fine. The config displaying the issue is the one where I do not explicitly map `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`. This will show tags as stale. See the gist here for a simple example: https://gist.github.com/cg-soft/62ac3529cf9ad6f6586e07866de43bc4

The output of that script (for me, running 2.3.5) is:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/christian.goetze/git/tag-merge-demo/origin/.git/
[master (root-commit) 953ecf0] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file.txt
Cloning into 'client'...
done.
To /Users/christian.goetze/git/tag-merge-demo/origin
 * [new tag]         PUBLIC_TAG -> PUBLIC_TAG
To /Users/christian.goetze/git/tag-merge-demo/origin
 * [new branch]      PRIVATE_TAG -> refs/private/tags/PRIVATE_TAG
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: /Users/christian.goetze/git/tag-merge-demo/origin
  Push  URL: /Users/christian.goetze/git/tag-merge-demo/origin
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master                        tracked
    refs/private/tags/PRIVATE_TAG tracked
    refs/tags/PUBLIC_TAG          stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master rebases onto remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
From /Users/christian.goetze/git/tag-merge-demo/origin
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> PUBLIC_TAG
 * [new tag]         PUBLIC_TAG -> PUBLIC_TAG
PRIVATE_TAG
PUBLIC_TAG
```

which clearly demonstrates the issue.

The workaround is to explicitly place `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` into your fetch settings in the config.

Comment: What version is your Git?  There was a fix in 2.0.0 (I think, I would have to re-check the release notes) to avoid counting refs as stale if there is at least one mapping into them.

Comment: Hm, yes, the release notes entry about this is for 2.0.0, and yours is newer, so that *should* be fixed now. Perhaps if you made a sample repository demonstrating the problem, the Git folks might fix it in 2.9 (or 2.9.1).  Incidentally, I don't know of any better way to do what you want: your approach seems right to me.

Comment: Does this depend also on the remote git version? I fear that might be the cause for the problem, since I tried to do as you suggested and run a pure local demo case, and it works fine there.

... and of course, gerrit using Jgit won't make this an easy fix...

Comment: It should not depend on the remote git, as it's just a question of scanning through *all* the references retrieved at the start of the `fetch` before declaring a mapping stale.  (I looked at the fix that went into 2.0.0 and it restructures this loop, which happens entirely on the client side.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I implemented this change over the weekend, and it lead to very significant performance improvements for most of the normal use cases. Specifically, gerrit performance improved a lot.